# Is the newTab inside ActionBar instantiated by ActionBarImpl?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am studying on the ActionBar and saw this abstract method

```
public abstract Tab newTab();
```

However the implementation of newTab is only seen in ActionBarImpl.java.

From android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

It is showed that

```
 final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
 bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
 bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

 mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
 mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Simple"), CountingFragment.class, null);
```

So, where is the bar.newTab() actually instantiated?

I saw a related post [What class should I extend, AcionBar or ActionBarImpl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644881/what-class-should-i-extend-acionbar-or-actionbarimpl) but it doesn't seem to answer my question directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionBar` class is an abstract class, like you already found out. It's actually implemented in the `ActionBarImp` class. Everything related to the ActionBar will be instantiated inside the `Activity` class. `getActionBar()` will return this implementation of the `ActionBar`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve a reference to this activity's ActionBar.
 *
 * @return The Activity's ActionBar, or null if it does not have one.
 */
public ActionBar getActionBar() {
    initActionBar();
    return mActionBar;
}

/**
 * Creates a new ActionBar, locates the inflated ActionBarView,
 * initializes the ActionBar with the view, and sets mActionBar.
 */
private void initActionBar() {
    [...]
    mActionBar = new ActionBarImpl(this);
    [...]
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1887-L1917).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Switching from c programming, I am still exploring java, just curious why it downcast it to ActionBar, instead of using ActionBarImpl? Isn't  it is more obvious if  
   
     final ActionBarImpl bar = getActionBar();

is used?